# How to read text from a flash movie (.swf)

Tags: php, flash

Today I realized that Google is indexing the text from flash movies and it's quite interesting to me how this can be achieved with any server-side language (PHP) for example ? Since it's a compiled file the only possible way that I tough it's by Optical Character Recognition.

**Edit:** [This is an example](https://www.google.bg/search?ix=heb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3ahttp://m.bgflash.com/) with all the flash movies that have been indexed for a Bulgarian flash website.

Comment: Do you have an example where google does that?

Comment: If they do indeed get text from flash files, I'd say it's rather more likely that they decompile them.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I've added an example inside the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that you might want to read: [SWF Searchability](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html).

Particularly, there is a paragraph that might be the key to the question you asked:

> Adobe has provided Flash Player technology to Google and Yahoo! that
>   allows their search spiders to navigate through a live SWF application
>   as if they were virtual users. The Flash Player technology, optimized
>   for search spiders, runs a SWF file similarly to how the file would
>   run in Adobe Flash Player in the browser, yet it returns all of the
>   text and links that occur at any state of the application back to the
>   search spider, which then appears in search results to the end user.

So, it seems they provided a specific flash player to those two search engines in order to make their content *crawlable* and that is why you can search by text that appear in the movie.  However, I am not really sure how you would do this with any server side language.